# Solenoid valve that does not restrict air flow when open

Tags: valves

I wonder if such a valve exist - a cheap solenoid valve that when open does not restrict air flow?
I've only found solenoid valves for compressed air, although the opening may very (4-12mm) there is a small hole inside no matter what.

This is the one I got but it's not what I need
[image]

*Motorized ball valves allow air to pass freely but I didn't found a small one and a cheap one.

I'm working on a simple project of a 5015 blower fan that I want to connect to a valve and sometimes allow air to pass, so I can maintain a small pressure difference between the inside and the outside.

I've also tried the plastic one-way valves but they also block most of the air.

Thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a shopping question.

Comment: Its about learning about other types of valves...

Comment: You must also be concerned about self cooling of electronics inside fan , thus a pressure vs flow vs hotspot rise and deflection vs blocking may be considered

Comment: This question looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please [edit] your question to give us a better idea of what you're trying to achieve with this design (not this specific problem you're facing, but what your actual objective is), and we'll be much better able to help you.

Comment: look at valves for paintball markers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If DIY is within your requirements, you can construct a device using a non-motorized ball valve. Attach a pneumatic cylinder (or long travel solenoid plunger) to the handle of the ball valve. Your signal to open/close will be the same as with the restrictive pneumatic valve but will have the desired effect of a ball valve, because it is a ball valve.

Cheap is subjective, and difficult to pin down without specifics.

[image: ball valve actuator sketch]

Image created by me. No scale, no proportions provided. Obviously, it will have to be modified to cover parameters such as length of solenoid stroke, force required to move the lever, etc. The solenoid in the diagram is placed at 45° in order to keep the forces balanced. If placed at a 90° orientation, forces would reach excessive levels to ensure closing or opening.

Comment: Thanks! I can 3d print!
I can dissemble the solenoid I have and attach it to something, but I didn't have an idea on how to make it fully sealed when closed...
Do you have any idea / sketch / model that I can look at for inspiration?